# candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const Node *') would lose const qualifier

Tags: c++, class, constants, qualifiers

I am writing a DiGraph (directed graph) class with the c++ built in `unordered_map<Node*, unordered_set<Edge>>` data structure, where Node and Edge are two structs I defined myself. And in the class I wrote a `containsNode()` method to search if a `Node` is in the graph. This is the `containsNode()` method body:

```
bool DiGraph::containsNode(const Node * n) const {
    auto::const_iterator it = digraph.find(n);
    return (it == digraph.end());
}
```

`digraph` is the private member of DiGraph of type `unordered_map<Node*, unordered_set<Edge>>`.

However, the compiler generates the following error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
auto::const_iterator it = digraph.find(n);
candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const Node *') would lose const qualifier
const_iterator find(const key_type& __k) const {return __t...
```

However, if I declare the method as 
`bool DiGraph::containsNode(Node* n) const {...}` (the only difference being that the `const` keyword removed from the argument list) then there is no compilation error.

I checked the C++ documentation and saw that the `find()` method declaration in the `unordered_map` container has the `const` keyword:

```
std::unordered_map::find
    const_iterator find(const Key& key) const;
```

Therefore I think there shouldn't be a compilation error, so why do I get one?

Answer (score 8):

`find()` looks like this: `find(const T& key)` If `T` is `Node*`, then `Node*` must be `const`. But note, the *pointer* must be `const`, NOT the value pointed at which `containsNode(const Node * n)` will give you. `find()` will give no assurances that the value pointed at by `n` will go untouched, and that violates `const Node * n`.

You are in a right pickle, my friend. Since your key *is* the pointer, you probably can't use a copy of the pointed-at value, different address, nor can you assign it to a non-`const` pointer that can be used by find. You can cast, but so much for respecting the `const`! Rethink how you are doing this, is my advice.

Bit easier to visualize with a set. Less overhead, same results.

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A
{

};

set<A*> test;

void func1(A *const  a) // pointer is const
{
    test.find(a); //Compiles, but not what you want.
    A b;
    a = &b; // Doesn't compile. Can't change where a points 
    *a = b; // compiles. Value at a is open game
}

void func2(const A *  a) // value is const
{
    test.find(a); //doesn't compile
    A b;
    a = &b; // compiles. Can change where a points
    *a = b; // does not compile. Can't change what a points at
    test.find((A*)a); //Compiles, but holy super yuck! Find a better way!
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    func1(&a);
    func2(&a);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right. So I guess I'd better use a Node instead of a Node* as the key value to ensure the const qualifier. Thank you very much!